# Reorder axis values to ascending values with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a simple ggplot2 jitter plot in R. For x values, I have integers between 1 and 100. When I plot this data my x axis start with a value of 1 then goes to `11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, etc.` How can I reorder my x axis to create ascending values (eg. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... etc.)?

Here is my code:

```
data = read.csv('my_data_file', sep"\t")
x_values = data[,1]
y_values = data[,2]  
qplot(rank, score, geom="jitter")
```

EDIT: I should have pointed out that I also have a few `non-integer` x values. Ideally, I would like the x axis to ascend by number and then have the `non-integer` values appended to the end of the x axis. Any order for the `non-integer` values is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph).  Or maybe not since this is continuous vs. barchart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert to numeric, as @gsk3 says, but as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/r-how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-in-r-without-a-loss-of-informa) answer points out, there are some difficulties, and you should use:

```
x_values <- as.numeric(levels(x_values))[x_values]
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked. I should have mentioned in my original question that I also have two 'non-integer' x-values. When I try this solution I get a warning message: `NAs introduced by coercion`. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: You would need to get rid of those beforehand. Assuming you want to assign a numeric x value to them you could use car::recode like this: `x_values <- recode(x_values,recodes="'non-integer x1'='10';'non-integer x2'='11'")` (although I'm not sure this is the most efficient way)

Comment: @ROLO Thanks for pointing out the error.  I shouldn't answer questions on my way out the door! :-)

Comment: @gsk3 You're welcome (I was somewhat amazed having to correct you using an answer you had already responded to yourself, but that explains it ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

Your `x` variable had quotes around it in the CSV (Excel is notorious for this), which means that R read it in as a factor, which it alphabetizes the levels by default.  Fix the levels and you'll fix the ordering.  Or better yet, since `x` seems to naturally want to be an integer, fix your data type:

```
x_values <- as.integer(as.character(x_values))
```

Try `str(data)` to see the data types of your columns.  If your data is big there are more efficient ways to convert.